# spring http request mapping single uri with different request parameters to different method is good practice or bad practice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My question is I need to implement rest api to search Students bases on its attributes
below are my urls.

```
    http/my system/vo1/students/search?firstname=ABC&responseType=summary
    http/my system/vo1/students/search?age=ABC&responseType=summary
    http/my system/vo1/students/search?id=ABC& responseType =summary
    http/my system/vo1/students/search?mobile=ABC& responseType =summary
    http/my system/vo1/students/search?lastname=ABC& responseType =summary
    http/my system/vo1/students/search?education=ABC& responseType=summary
    http/my system/vo1/students/search?working=ABC& responseType =summary
    http/my system/vo1/students/search? responseType =summary
```

responseType can be summary,hierarchy or can more types will be added in feature.

So i have single URI "/my system/vo1/students/search?" with different parameters
and user will send max two optional parameters and min is one is mandatory that is responseType

in spring we can map single uri with different request parameters to different method as shown below

```
@RequestMapping(value = “my system/vo1/students/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public Students  searchStudentByName(
                @RequestParam(value = “name",required = true) String name,
                @RequestParam(value = “ responseType", required = true) String responseType)
    {
            //do student fetching works
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = “my system/vo1/students/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public Students  searchStudentByAge(
                @RequestParam(value = “age",required = true) int age,
                @RequestParam(value = “ responseType", required = true) String responseType)
    {
            //do student fetching works
    }
```

and so on .. we can write 9 different methods for this .

one  more way is to do it create only one method.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = “my system/vo1/students/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public Students  searchStudentByAge(
                @RequestParam(value = “firstname",required = true) String age,
                @RequestParam(value = “age",required = false) int age,
                @RequestParam(value = “lastname",required = false) String lastname,
                @RequestParam(value = “working",required = false) String working,
             //add more for each field that will be present in url...........
                @RequestParam(value = “ responseType", required = true) String responseType)
    {
            //do student fetching works
    }
```

In second approach we can write separate validator to validate the input request.

I have below Questions

1. which approach is best (considering best design principals and practices)
2. why it is best approach
3. what is best object oriented design for such problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go with one RequestMapping in this scenario (the 2nd option). What if you later want to combine query params? Combinatorial Explosion!

Make sure you understand the JPA Criteria API, or check out Jooq and QueryDSL. That will make life easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

One method will suffice with a Pathvariable for responseType. Also you can move your search parameters to SearchCriteria class and perform validation for by JSR303

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/search/{responseType}", method =RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Students  searchStudent(@Pathvariable String responseType, @RequestBody @valid SearchCriteria criteria, BindingResult result)
    {    
     if(result.hasErrors()){
        // deal with your validation errors here
       }
     // Result= SearchService.search(criteria);
    }
```

And your Search criteria will look like

```
Class SearchCriteria{
@NotEmpty
@Getter @Setter private String firstname;

@Min(1)
@Getter @Setter int age;

}
```

More validation constraints [here](http://hibernate.org/validator/)

Spring MVC and JSR303 example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/)

Comment: Thanks for reply.All the criteria is not coming by post  method call they are request parameter.will @RequestBody annotation will work with HTTP Get method?.

Comment: Yes, it will, but that is a different question, if the current issue is resolved , you can accept the answer and open a new question

Comment: I have written code above, but it is giving me org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input
when i have submit Http Get http/my system/vo1/students /search/summary?firstname=abc&age=4

Comment: Open a different question

Comment: sorry but you're solution is not working for me.I am looking best solution to my problem..I have already two solutions as i mentioned above.